# Property 'combineLatest' doesnt exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, combinelatest

Hello I am using RxJS `combineLatest` operator and getting this error. Could someone let me know what changes I should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please don't post screenshots of code. It makes it stupid hard to reproduce the issue.
2. In the latest versions of RxJS, `combineLatest` is static akin to `forkJoin`. So you need to initialize an observable out of it. See v5 -> v6 [migration guide](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration) and search for `combineLatest`.

```js
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

this.searchResult = combineLatest(this.searchQuery$, this.listMachines).pipe(...);
```